# create strdup in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write the following function in C,

`char* modelstrdup(char* source);`

The function should imitate the standard C library function `strdup`. The parameter is the string that we wish to duplicate. The returned pointer will point onto the heap. When you write this function, create a structure `string` on the heap that holds a copy of source. Set the length and capacity of your String equal to the number of characters in source. Be
sure to return the address to the first character in the string and not the address of the structure string.

This is the only hint my professor gave me, but I don't even know where to start...

```
//Client Program Format only, will not work!
char* s; // should be “yo!” when we‟re done
String* new_string = malloc(sizeof(String) + 10 + 1);
(*new_string).length = 3; // 3 characters in “yo!”
(*new_string).capacity = 10; // malloced 10 bytes
(*new_string).signature = ~0xdeadbeef;
(*new_string).ptr[0] = „y‟;
(*new_string).ptr[1] = „o‟;
(*new_string).ptr[2] = „!‟;
(*new_string).ptr[3] = 0;
s = (*new_string).ptr;
printf(“the string is %s\n”, s);
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: This question is not very clear. Can you let us know what part of the problem you are having trouble with.

Comment: `(*new_string).ptr[1] = „o‟;` Yikes! Where did you get the `„` and `‟` from?

Comment: @pmg - I suspect it's a function of the cut and paste or keyboard the OP is using that's mapped " to „

Comment: I have a better question -- why do you think WE should do your homework for you?  All you'll learn that way is how to get someone else to do your work for you.  If that's what you want to do, you should be working on an MBA, not programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heres a hint

```
char* strdup(char *str)
{
        char* ret = (char*)malloc(strlen(str)+1);

        //copy characters here
        return ret;
}
```